# windows forms app.config on common files folder

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, app-config

I have an application that stores single username and password on the app.config file.
I currently have the app.config writable on runtime so that the user will be able to change it.

problem begins upon installation using a setup project , the app.config is installed on the program files which is not writable for any user.

So , i have changed the app.config location upon installation to the common files folder so it will be accessible for reading and writing for all users.

Now, upon installation it seems that the data stored there is inaccessible at all , using ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["networkPath"] for example returns empty strings.

what am i doing wrong ?

Comment: what u need to do is give access to just the app config file in program files from your installer. what setup do u use for that?

Comment: im using the default setup and deployment project, how can i give access to the app config file ?

Comment: You mean the msi one from visual studio? It has to have an option though I am not very sure. But forget it, you can do it from your C# application. See my answer

Comment: Can you use an application settings file instead? This will localize itself to the user's app data folder and therefore not involve any change in permissions to the installation items (which are usually meant to be read only when in the Program Files directory).

Comment: @Reddog accessing appconfig file, the default one is faster since its loaded when assembly is loaded. It need not do write each time you want a value from it. But yes thats an alternative too

Comment: im trying to use application settings but how do i get the value ? Properties.Settings.Default.networkPath is not working so is Properties.Settings.Default.Properties["networkPath"]

Comment: @liorr - There is a designer and generated accessor class to make it easy if using Visual Studio. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: ok , got it working with application.settings - the file is accessible for all users but ... Properties.Settings.Default.Save(); is not saving the changed values :-(

Comment: ok, got it all working , thank you all for your help. finally used - application.settings + Properties.Settings.Default.mysettingspropertyname + Properties.Settings.Default.Save();  thank you , and thank you again :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in two ways:

1. Give special permission to app config file in program files by your installer. We do it using innosetup. If you are incapable of it, then do it from your program startup:

   ```
   static void Main()
   {
       GrantAccess()
   }

   private static bool GrantAccess()
   {
       FileInfo fInfo = new FileInfo(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location + ".config");
       FileSecurity dSecurity = fInfo .GetAccessControl();
       fSecurity.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule("everyone", 
                                                        FileSystemRights.FullControl, 
                                                        AccessControlType.Allow));
       fInfo .SetAccessControl(fSecurity);
       return true;
   }
   ```
2. Else you can choose another location to place your appconfig file, and then read it like this:

   ```
   ExeConfigurationFileMap fileMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
   fileMap.ExeConfigFilename = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData), Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetName().Name) + ".exe.config";
   Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(fileMap, 
                                                                          ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
   return config.AppSettings.Settings["Key"].Value);
   ```

This is a poor choice in my opinion.